Can placing a comma inside a quotation be misconstrued as original punctuation?
I am writing a book review, following Turabian Style guidlines, and am trying to figure out  whether placing a comma inside the quotes misconstrues the original sentence in a particular example. I want to change the portion of my review that I am placing in bold (not original emphasis) below,

In chapter one, Kruger begins by defining his concepts and approach. He speaks of canonical models which represent “one’s canonical ‘worldview’” and indicate the basis of someone’s concept of canon using “methodological, epistemological, and, yes, even theological frameworks...” Kruger writes: “We will be categorizing the various models not on the basis of date or definition of canon (as is commonly done), but in regard to the method of authenticating canon.”

to this:

In chapter one, Kruger begins by defining his concepts and approach. He speaks of canonical models which represent “one’s canonical ‘worldview’,” indicating the basis of someone’s concept of canon using “methodological, epistemological, and, yes, even theological frameworks...” Kruger writes: “We will be categorizing the various models not on the basis of date or definition of canon (as is commonly done), but in regard to the method of authenticating canon.”

These are the words in the source1 for the portion in question:

A canonical model, then, is one's canonical "worldview."

Note how my source places the word worldview in double quotes of its own (not as a quotation but to otherwise set it off from the other words) and ends the sentence by placing the period inside the double quotes.
When I convert that into something I am quoting, I have to first make the typical conversion of the original double quotes to single quotes; but then it seems like I must not only omit the original period but also add a comma after the closing of the single quotes in my preferred example. Is that allowable? My reader might not know that was the end of a sentence in the original text.
A closely related question is whether in a case where the original sentence had continued (say: "one's canonical 'worldview' or rather 'philosophy.'"), would the comma possibly be mistaken as belonging in the quote proper as if it has read "one's canonical 'worldview,' or rather 'philosophy'"?
References
1 Michael J. Kruger, Canon Revisited: Establishing the Origins and Authority of the New Testament Books (Wheaton, Ill.: Crossway, 2012), 28.

You’ve changed the meaning between the first passage and second by changing and indicate to indicating. In the first, canonical models represent and indicate. In the second, he indicates and canonical models represent. Which one are you aiming for?

Yes, good observation. I want the second one (with "indicating"), because I am restating what he means (which is explained in the surrounding paragraphs). In fact, I wrote the second (preferred) version first, but then backed off of it since I was unsure about the placement of the comma. I was quite unsatisfied with "and indicate," but I had to choose something for contrast.

Peripheral: I suggest that using "" for all his quotations except one, and in that instance using "" for your own input, risks confusion and is somewhat "untidy. I suggest (and I am absolutely not an authority on such matters) that you use '' for your quotations OR change ALL of his to '' so that you can then use "". [I hope that that makes sense in context - out of context it is probably unintelligible :-) ]

He describes canonical models as the “methodological, epistemological, and, yes, even theological" frameworks that represent “one’s canonical ‘worldview.’” (all punctuation inside)

Russell, perhaps my wording wasn't the clearest. These are all my source's words, not mine: //A canonical model, then, is one's canonical "worldview."// I did not use double quotes around any of my own words, so I have avoided the problem you suggest.

@TinfoilHat Since extended discussion is not permitted in the comments, suffice it to say that while rewording and rearranging can always be attempted (your efforts are appreciated), this question presents a "Give a man a fish, and he will eat for a day / Teach a man to fish, and he will eat for a lifetime" situation. Either the second example is acceptable or it is not, and that is all I really need to know, because I can apply it in other writing situations. Just because it looks funny to me with the comma placement doesn't necessarily mean it is wrong.

According to this commas go inside quotation marks in Chicago/Turabian (even if they're not part of the quoted text). Which may seem silly but if you know the convention it should be obvious what's happening.

All changes must be clearly indicated when quoting. Paraphrasing is less strictly governed, but any change in meaning is unacceptable.

@EdwinAshworth, the Chicago rules say to place commas inside of quotations. Is that or is that not changing it? (If it is the CMOS rules would be at fault for telling writers to add punctuation where it doesn't belong). What is your point in this case?

Strictly, if you quote gibberish, with seven-point ellipses and interrobangs and emoticons, you should preserve all characters (including spaces).  or clearly indicate where you're adding/subtracting. // Are you sure you're not confusing quotations = direct speech recorded in print and quotations = faithful reproduction of a printed original?

@EdwinAshworth You are wrong about the case of adding at the end, because CMOS rules do not mark where you have added a comma or period by anything more than its actual presence. There is no such convention as, say, placing square brackets around a period that CMOS told you HAD to be placed within the content bounded between quotation marks rather than after the final quotation mark. There simply isn't. Also, yes I know very well what a quotation does. It is always faithful reproduction of the original material bounded by quotation marks. This is not something limited to direct discourse.

@EdwinAshworth If you think there is a mechanism that CMOS designates for marking off the terminal period it tells you must mandatorily be placed inside a quotation that ends your own sentence in which it was quoted, then please leave an official answer below citing where CMOS does that. Same for a comma. Note, however: "In Chicago style, periods and commas go inside closing quotation marks, “like this,” whereas Oxford puts them after, ‘like this’, though there are exceptions. . ." https://news.uchicago.edu/explainer/chicago-manual-style-explained

CMoS is not the absolute arbiter in such matters. If I had to report a written answer downmarked for poor punctuation to a moderator, I might have to write "Candidate submitted 'The cat sat on the mat..'." Clarity trumps arbitrary style considerations (note that style guides disagree on some conventions, which is hardly workable). Essentially, in faithfully representing a written/printed original, a snapshot or equivalent is necessary.

The relationship between quotes and punctuation is a matter of style. According to The Chicago Manual of Style (the American English book publisher’s style guide of choice and from which Turabian style comes), the comma should be inside both the single and double quotes:

He speaks of canonical models which represent “one’s canonical
‘worldview,’ ” indicating . . .

Here’s an example from CMOS:

“My favorite story,” I told them, “is called ‘Interpreter of
Maladies.’ ”

As an aside . . . That example occurs under “6.11: Single quotation marks next to double quotation marks,” which mainly discusses the use of a thin space between single and double quotes (as shown above following worldview, and Maladies.):

When . . . two of the marks appear next to each other, a space between
the two marks, though not strictly required, aids legibility . . .

Your typographer will insert the thin space, or you may do that yourself in your word processing program.
(If you’re really torn up about all this, use an em dash: He speaks of canonical models which represent “one’s canonical ‘worldview’ ”—indicating . . .)

While your example with the thin space is interesting, it seems to also be an aside. I guess there is no rule against how to quote something at the very end of a sentence differently from any other part of a sentence? In any case the suggestion to use an em dash is intriguing. Thanks for that suggestion.

Yes, everything I wrote after “As an aside...” is an aside. And no, there is no difference between the treatment of an internal comma and a terminal period.

However accurately you cite it, nothing The Chicago Manual nor any other style guide has to say could alter the fact, quotation marks exist solely to show that what's within them is meant literally. That's there raison d'etre. The one exception is when ellipses (…) is used within the quotes to mean that something was left out.
Why is that hard to follow, please?
